# Some items suggested for updating by Discover always can't be updated

Tags: 18.04, updates, kubuntu

I have Kubuntu 18.04 and always the first two items in the updates items suggested by "Application Updates" remain as the same every time the update notification alert appears as shown in the following screen shot:

[image]

I don't know what is the reason of this issue or how to remove these two items. I have tried to remove Quasi Deepin but it seems to be unmoved from the updates list.

Comment: Could you please explain how you "tried to remove Quasi Deepin"? What steps did you take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have installed Quasi Deepin via *System Settings > Application Style > Window Decorations > Get New Decorations*, you could open the same GUI again and click the uninstall button against the name of the decoration you installed.

[image: Remove Quasi Deepin]

A similar route is used to remove *Simply Circles*: open *System Settings > Icons* instead.

---

Alternatively, you could open *Discover*, select the *Installed* category and then use the search bar to look for *quasi* or whatever else. The item will be listed with a *Remove* option.

---

I don't use Discover much and so I don't know how it would update software from the KDE Store.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with Terminal (Command Prompt). Open terminal and type these command and enter-

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then you can also try

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```